# Iptables NAT for ICMP echo_request, DNAT error

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking, nat

on VirtualBox I have 3 VM, one router and two hosts. The router has 3 interfaces, 2 of which linked with the host, and another with the physical interface of the real Host (my laptop). The two host can ping each other, the router forwarding is enabled, and now I want to perform a NAT operation in the third interface (called enp0s9), to perform ping request to remote servers (in Internet). So I'm using iptables with the following commands:

```
    sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.2 -p icmp --icmp-type any -o enp0s9 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.6:25000
    sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.6:25000 -p icmp --icmp-type any -i enp0s9 -j DNAT --to-dest 192.168.1.2
```

where 192.168.1.2 is one of the two host, and 192.168.1.6 is enp0s9 IP addr (I have done the same thing for the other host interface, switching port) .
The error I receive is

> host/network 192.168.1.6:25000 not found

How can I fix the error for the DNAT operation?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by changing the port with ICMP?! http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml

Comment: When the remote server responds to the icmp echo request to my router interface enp0s9, my router must change the destination address, and this could be done with a port (this is what I thought)